# What does minus 1 mean after calling to_i?

Tags: ruby, integer

```
class.all[variable.to_i - 1]
```

Just trying to understand what "- 1" means after `to_i` and why it's between brackets.

Comment: It means "subtract one from the left operand" (the left operand being`variable.to_i` in this case)

Comment: It's inside the brackets because the value of the expression `variable.to_i - 1` is the desired index into the `class.all` array

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby `variable.to_i - 1` subtracts 1 from the value of `variable.to_i`.

When used in the context of an array, this is often done to get the desired index, since indices start at 0.

For example, I have three items: `<#Item id=1>, <#Item id=2>, <#Item id=3>`

I can subtract one to get the index.

```
id = 3 
Item.all[id - 1]  #=> <#Item id=3>
```

Comment: Having `<#Item id=1>` and `Item.all` makes it look like a Rails example. Since this isn't a Rails question, you might want to turn that into a pure Ruby example instead.